# Can I install from source when already have the repo package?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, virtualbox

I just tried to install Virtualbox from source on Ubuntu, but it didn't let me because I already have the repo package. I need to have both versions ideally. Is it possible for me to install from source in such a way that it gets around this restriction?

The following is the error message following a sudo dpkg -i command on the deb package:

```
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.1.
dpkg: regarding virtualbox-5.1_5.1.18-114002-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb containing virtualbox-5.1:
 virtualbox-5.1 conflicts with virtualbox
  virtualbox-5.0 provides virtualbox and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive virtualbox-5.1_5.1.18-114002-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing virtualbox-5.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.1_5.1.18-114002-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb
```

Comment: If it was not a virtual machine then yes. However if you read the manual, it says do not run with other virtual machines. (Though it does say that you can have two (different ones) installed. But as they patch the kernel (this may be done cleaner these days), there would probably be a conflict.

Comment: What do you mean by did not let me? Show what you did, and the error message.

Comment: ok, added the error message and my own installation attempt command

Comment: You say you are “installing from source”, but then show you installing using `dpkg`.

Comment: If you are installing a deb from Sun (Orical), or Ubuntu, then use `apt` to install it not `dpkg`. You will have to add the repo to  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: You are not about to install the package from source . see here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux%20build%20instructions

Answer (score 0):

You can't install two versions of the same package through the package manager. (This is how APT works — there are other package managers that work differently.) If you try to install a second version, it replaces the old one.

It is possible to install multiple version of some programs with APT. This is done by adding the program version in the package name. It's typically done for libraries, because you may have multiple programs installed using different versions of the same library. This is actually happening with VirtualBox: you're trying to install `virtualbox-5.1` with `virtualbox-5.0` already installed. In terms of package names, that's possible. However, these packages can't actually be installed together; the package metadata contains conflict information which tells the package manager not to install them together. Even if the package metadata didn't declare a conflict, the two packages could not be installed together, because they provide files with the same name. I don't know why VirtualBox comes in packages whose name contain the version of the software.

If you want to install multiple versions of VirtualBox, you'll have to install them from a binary distribution or from source, without using the package manager. In other words, don't get a deb file (except perhaps for one of the versions).